# How I can get correct stack trace at Unity3d (iOS)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, stack-trace

My code:

```
try
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", "original");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string exception = ex.ToString();
    }
```

But correct stack trace getting only in Unity's editor.

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter cannot be null
Parameter name: original
at MyClassName (System.String message) [0x00026] in /Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/myPackageName/xxx/xxx/xxx/myClassName.cs:104
```

At the device stack trace is such:

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter cannot be null
Parameter name: original
at MyClassName(System.String message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction.Invoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1].Invoke (.T1 handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchPress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData pointerEvent, Boolean pressed, Boolean released) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Why in Unity's editor I have file name and line number at stacktrace, but at this iOS device I haven't this?

It's a development build

Comment: Just think - how it could work on compiled build??

Comment: There is no way to get the data on compiled build?

Comment: There is now way to get source file line, anywhere, but also for iOS il2cpp filename is not supported, so no, unfortunately no.

Comment: I don't know how they do it, but they have line numbers with this tool: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/getting-started-game-performance-reporting

Answer (score 0):

When making an ios build in Unity, Check Development Build in the build dialog. Also, in the drop down, choose Run in Xcode as Debug. In build settings, turn off the strip symbols checkbox.

This will include the symbols in the build, and will allow filename and line numbers to be reported.

Answer (score 0):

You can have line numbers on C# Exceptions with IL2CPP builds when using [Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/unity/). Works on iOS, Android, Windows, macOS and Linux players.

Works on 2020.3 and newer.

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/unity/configuration/il2cpp/